# How to do a parallel search for a strings in files

Tags: python

I wrote this simple code for searching for strings in a collection of files. It works but is not optimal.

1. I need to hardcode file names in a dictionary
2. some of my files are about 60Mb of size, search lasts for a while

Could someone please optimize my code for the following:

- read all files in a given directory without the need to hardcode the file names
- parallelize the search for speed
- write the search result in a output.txt file

  ```
  my_file = {"File1.xml", "File2.xml", "File3.xml"} 
  my_string = {"John", "Mary", "Clara"}

   for f in my_file:

      for s in my_string:
          with open(f) as fp:
              a = fp.read().count(s)
              fp.close()
          print f,',',s,',',a
  ```

Thank you

Comment: This is too broad. Describe one particular question with your attempts to solve this particular issue in one post. "Please do all my work for me" is not welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Read the files:

```
files_queue = Queue()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    for file in files:
        files_queue.put(file)
```

### 2. Parallel search:

```
res_queue = Queue()
threads = []

def search(files_queue, words, res_queue):
    while True:
        file = files_queue.get(block=Flase)

        with open(file) as fp:
            content = fp.read()
            results = {}

            for word in words
                results[word] = content.count(s)

        res_queue.put(results)
        files_queue.task_done()

# use 10 workers   
for _ in range(10):
    thread = Thread(target=search, args=(files_queue, words, res_queue) 
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

### 3. Collect results:

```
# wait until all files processed
files.join() 

# collect results from queue
results = []
while not res_queue.empty()
   results.append( res_queue.get() )

# profit
...
```

Comment: I left writing out results for you. Plus you could further speed it up with better pattern searching, regexp perhaps? You could match several patterns at the same time.

Comment: I've got an "invalid syntax" error at threads.append(thread) pointing at 's' in threads

Comment: It looks like I need to import some modules. Which do I need to import?